# rvest does not extract self-closing xml-nodes

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

Trying to parse this xml-file:
http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?latitude=48.9905&longitude=-122.2733&showall=false

`rvest`/`xml2` seams not to recognize the nodes correctly:

```
require(rvest) #which uses xml2 internally
doc <- read_xml("http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?latitude=48.9905&longitude=-122.2733&showall=false")
> doc
{xml_document}
<Response>
[1] <Block FIPS="530730102002091"/>
[2] <County FIPS="53073" name="Whatcom"/>
[3] <State FIPS="53" code="WA" name="Washington"/>
```

Trying to get the *County* node i did - what results in an Error (no matches)

```
doc %>% xml_node("County") # Error: No matches
```

I also tried it via `read_html` and `httr::GET` combined with both: `read_html` and `read_xml`...
Any Idea`

P.S.: The example is taken from here: [Parsing an XML response to a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164392/parsing-an-xml-response-to-a-query). I tried to solve this one via `rvest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doc has a namespace, `xmlns`, you can examine it with `xml_ns`, and use the prefix in your xpath,

```
xml_find_one(doc, "//d1:County", xml_ns(doc))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to use rvest with a namespace? So to use a css-selector with instead of the xpath

Comment: I don't know how, it looks like might be possible, but im not sure sorry